Evaluation of Stieltjes Integral
Let $\pi(x)$ be a real valued function with asymptotic formula $\pi(x)\sim \frac{x}{\log x}$. I want to get an asymptotic formular for the Stieltjes integral
$$\int_{1}^{x} y^{ia}d\pi(y)$$
when $x\to \infty$. Here $a$ is a real number.
The book I read says the answer is $\frac{x^{ia}}{1+ia}\pi(x)$, but I can't figure out how to derive this. Any help would be appreciated!

Write $\pi(x)=\int_2^x{\mathrm dy\over\log y}+R(x)$, so $\mathrm d\pi(y)={1\over\log y}+\mathrm dR(y)$. Perform integration by parts and apply $R(y)=O(y/\log^2y)$ should work.
